XSD 1.0 nillable with xs:string type enumeration restriction base
I wanted to confirm my understanding of the XSD nillable attribute as it pertains to a restriction base that enforces an enumeration. For example given the following:
<xs:complexType name="_fruits">
  <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="fruit" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="apple"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="banana"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="pear"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="orange"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:compexType>
<xs:element name="fruits" type="_fruits"/>

The following fails schema validation:
<fruits>
  <fruit>apple</fruit> <!-- ok -->
  <fruit>banana</fruit> <!-- ok -->
  <fruit xsi:nil="true"/> <!-- not ok -->
</fruits>

What are the options to allow a null value? One that comes to mind is creating a nullable type and then using a union
<xs:simpleType name="_nullableType"> <!-- the nullable type -->
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name= "_fruit"> <!-- the restriction base fruit -->
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="apple"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="banana"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="pear"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="orange"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="_nullableFruit"> <!-- a union of the restriction base and nullable -->
    <xs:union memberTypes="_fruit _nullableType"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="nullableFruit" type="_nullableFruit"/>
<xs:complexType name="_fruits"> <!-- complex type -->
  <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="nullableFruit" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:compexType>

However, whilst the above has the desired effect it is very complicated. Any other options would be gratefully received.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732264/minoccurs-0-and-nillable-true

What library or program are you using to validate the XML? The first schema with the example  XML absolutely works fine in both Java and .NET validators, and also works fine in Oxygen XML when you add the xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" and  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SO78721120.xsd" attributes.

Did you actually declare the xsi namespace? (If you had shown us the error message then we wouldn't need to ask...)
My preferred way to do this is to declare fruit as being a list type with minLength = 0, maxLength = 1.
I don't like using xsi:nil, it seems quite unnecessarily complicated.

Thanks @Michael - yes, in the real world problem space the xsi namespace is defined.
